# Approval Process Rejection Alert to Initial Submitter

Tags: approval-process

We have approval processes in place for our Knowledge Articles.  We have to have a different approval process for each article type.  The business process allows for anyone to submit an article for approval, not just the record creator.

The issue comes when someone rejects the article for whatever reason.  For the rejection email alert, there are many options for the recipient, such as public groups, queues, record creator, etc.  There is no option however to send the rejection alert to the person that submitted the article for approval, at least not that I can see (I'm hoping I'm just being really dense and missing it).  So right now, if the article was submitted by someone other than the creator, which happens a lot in our case, then the person who wrote the article gets the alert, not the person that submitted the article.  I know we can send it to the user that last modified the article, but this doesn't help in the case where a person didn't modify the article, just submitted for approval.

**Use Case**

> We formerly used Solutions, and had thousands of solutions in the system.  As there is no real great way to migrate solutions to knowledge articles, we had a temp hired to manually do this.  We have a log in say Temp@companyName.com that logs in to SF and created all these articles from old solutions.  Now we are having our support agents send them through the approval process (they are not necessarily editing the article before submitting them which is why the last modified by user doesn't work either).  When they are rejected, the rejections are going to the email for the temp user, not the person that submitted the article for approval, which is causing a lot of issues.

This seems like such a simple concept and I really can't imagine it isn't possible, I just can't seem to find a way to do it.

**Am I crazy, or is this not possible?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but what about updating an email field with the email address of the person who submitted the approval as an initial action? Then when you need to email that user you could use that field.

Comment: Do you mean having this email address as a custom field on the article type?

Comment: Yes, as an initial action you could update a custom field (email type) with the email address of the user submitting the approval.

Comment: That's an interesting work around, thank you.  So I take it that you are confirming that there is no way to natively do this?  It seems like such a simple thing to not be available as an option

Comment: Luckily is an easy work around. Here is the idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpa5AAC

Comment: Ok, I'm glad to know that it isnt possible, was startying to think I was just missing something.  I voted the idea, not that it really means anything as its been open for 5 years, lol.  Thanks a lot.